# Dictionary Values in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am trying to access values I've set in a Swift dictionary.  The dictionary has a `String` for the keys and values.  My intent is to use the dictionary to set a string variable as I work through a series of URLs.  In Objective-C I understand how this works.  I have a string property called currentFeed that I pass the value of the dictionary to.

```
self.currentFeed = [NSString stringWithString: [self.URLDictionary objectForKey: @"FLO Cycling"]];
```

In Swift I am having a difficult time with this.  I tried the following code and receive an error message.

```
self.currentFeed = self.URLDictionary["FLO Cycling"]

Error Message: "Cannot subscript a value of type '[String:String]' with an index of type 'String'.
```

For reference the dictionary was created in Swift in the following way.  The constants were created with lets.

```
let kFLOCyclingURL = "http://flocycling.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss"
let kTriathleteURL = "http://triathlon.competitor.com/feed"
let kVeloNewsURL = "http://velonews.competitor.com/feed"
let kCyclingNewsURL = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/cyclingnews/news?format=xml"
let kRoadBikeActionURL = "http://www.roadbikeaction.com/news/rss.aspx"
let kIronmanURL = "http://feeds.ironman.com/ironman/topstories"
```

The items were added to the dictionary with keys.

```
let URLTempDictionary = ["FLO Cycling" : kFLOCyclingURL, "Triathlete" : kTriathleteURL, "Velo News" : kVeloNewsURL, "Cycling News" : kCyclingNewsURL, "Road Bike Action" : kRoadBikeActionURL, "Ironman" : kIronmanURL]
```

Thanks for any help.

Take care,

Jon

Comment: How is `currentFeed` declared?

Comment: currentFeed is declared with the following.  

var currentFeed : String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles fine for me. The only thing I noticed was that your dictionary is named URLTempDictionary and you're accessing URLDictionary. :)

Option a (safest, most robust)

```
if let dict = self.URLDictionary
{
    self.currentFeed = dict["FLO Cycling"]
}
```

Option b (use with caution, possible runtime error)

```
self.currentFeed = dict!["FLO Cycling"]
```

Comment: Sorry for the mix up.  I am passing it from one class to another with an init method.  That's why there is a difference in the name.

Comment: Ahh I see, no worries. Is self.URLDictionary declared optional by chance?

Comment: It is.  I just removed the optional and it fixed the problem.  The reason I added it in the first place is because the compiler complained it was empty.  Is there a way to declare a dictionary as an optional?  Maybe there isn't.  I guess if I know the dictionary values it would make the most sense to fill it when it is declared.

Comment: Sure, you can declare just about anything as an optional you just have to make sure to unwrap it in one of two ways, using the " if let " pattern (safest, robust) or the "forced unwrap" pattern. The latter is just for situations where you know with complete certainty that the optional will not be null.

Comment: See above for an example of each.

Comment: When I type 

var URLDicitonary : [String:String]?

and then 

self.currentFeed = self.URLDictionary["FLO Cycling"]!

I get the following error.

"Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments"

Any thoughts?